# Why do inline-block divs get screwed up by internal content?

Tags: html, css

I dont understand why inline-block divs are losing their position due to the addition of internal content.

My CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 80px;
    width: 66%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
}
#header-left {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 25%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(128,0,0);
}
#header-center {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(0,128,0);
    text-align: center;
}
#header-right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,128);
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div id=header-bar><div id=header><div id=header-left></div><div id=header-center><div>Hello</div></div><div id=header-right></div></div></div>
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ude04hf4/

I want to add internal content and not have it affect its parent's position. The only way I have found to do this is to add float: left; to every internal element's style. There has to be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `vertical-align` property value of the element.

By default, the [`vertical-align` property's value is `baseline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height), which is why the center element's text is being aligned to the previous element's baseline (notice that this issue doesn't occur when the element doesn't contain text).

If you change the `vertical-align` property value to something like `top`, it will work as expected:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dczuvwc2/)

```
#header-center {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 80px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(0,128,0);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Such a simple solution. Thanks Josh